# Can the word collective be used for a thing/content created by group of people

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

In a tweet, I want to refer a group as collective and the things they create together as a collective. Will that be right.

Comment: Could you please tell us the **nature of your endeavor**? Try translating the question into your language, with no context, and perhaps you will understand what I mean....In art circles, the word collective is often used. Also, in the maker community. These are just examples.

Comment: The word _collective_ has been used in a number of ways; and tweeting, as has been demonstrated, has no "right" and "wrong".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition of Collective

adjective:
done by people acting as a group.
"a collective protest"

noun:
a cooperative enterprise.
"The exhibition showcases the work of art collectives from more than 20 countries."

So in short yes.  You can use it as an adjective or as a noun.